# using PHP convert the string values to array and get the values

Tags: php

my `$data` returns following values.the `gettype()` of the following values is a `String`.

```
["0:12:23", 0.000000],["0:12:43", 0.000000],["0:13:03", 0.000000]
```

I want to convert the string vlaues to an array.and have to out  the time values `"0:12:23" , "0:12:43" and "0:13:03"`

How can i conver the string values to array using php and get the time vlaues only.

Comment: the input is in single string or three different string?

Comment: This looks *almost* like JSON…!? `json_decode` it?

Comment: the input is the whol;e string ["0:12:23", 0.000000],["0:12:43", 0.000000],["0:13:03", 0.000000]

Comment: Then `json_decode("[$data]")` should do as a first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I hope that your input is in single string.So do like below:-***

```
<?php

$string = '["0:12:23", 0.000000],["0:12:43", 0.000000],["0:13:03", 0.000000]'; // i assume it's a single string
preg_match_all('/\d:\d{2}:\d{2}/',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/895248

***Or as @deceze  said use `json_decode("[$string]")` like below:-***

```
<?php
  $string = '["0:12:23", 0.000000],["0:12:43", 0.000000],["0:13:03", 0.000000]';
  $string_array=json_decode("[$string]");
  $time_array = array_column($string_array,0);
  print_r($time_array);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/895251

Reference:-

[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: is print_r($matches[0]) returns the first time value?

Comment: @Psl  no. it will return array of all time

Comment: You can do:- `$final_time_array = $matches[0]; echo $final_time_array[0];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_decode` to convert it into array structure.and use `foreach` loop to filter out .try below,

```
<?php
$string = '["0:12:23", 0.000000],["0:12:43", 0.000000],["0:13:03", 0.000000]';
$string_to_array=json_decode("[$string]");
foreach($string_to_array as $values){  
print_r($values[0]); 
}
?>
```